# KKT optimisation - condition of inequality constraint being zero

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

For example, given the following:

Minimise
$$
f(x_1, x_2)
$$

Subject to 
$$
h(x_1, x_2) = 0
$$

$$
g(x_1, x_2) \leq 0
$$

The KKT conditions are written out as

$$
l(x, \lambda, \mu) = 
f(x_1, x_2) + 
\lambda h(x_1, x_2) + 
\mu g(x_1, x_2)
$$

And one of the conditions is that

$$
\mu \cdot g(x_1, x_2) = 0
$$

I'm not sure why this condition is necessary though, I think that it has something to do with the constraint being active / inactive and/or there being slack? I'm not sure what the reasoning is though.

Comment: There's not quite enough information to answer this question. What conditions are you assuming on f, h, and g?

Comment: f is just some function, g and h are the conditions. If you want to assume that they're all polynomials that would be fine for this.

Comment: The KKT conditions apply to convex problems in standard form, which is a lot stricter than just "polynomials". That specific condition actually applies whenever "strong duality" holds, which is more general. The KKT conditions guarantee that strong duality holds, and apply when f, g are convex and differentiable, and when h is affine.

Comment: I see the tag [tag:convex-optimization] but no convexity.

Answer (score 3):

The condition $\mu \cdot g(x_1,x_2) = 0$ is a *complementary slackness condition*. It says that either the dual multiplier $\mu$ is 0, or there is no slack in the $g(x_1,x_2) \le 0$ constraint.

The dual values give the change in the optimal objective function value if the right-hand side of the constraint changes. So the intuition behind the complementary slackness condition is that if there is slack in the constraint ($g(x_1,x_2) \lneqq 0$), then changing the RHS would have no effect on the optimal objective function value, hence $\mu=0$. And, if $\mu \ne 0$, then a change in RHS would lead to a change in the objective function, so the constraint must be tight ($g(x_1,x_2) = 0$).